# What results from particle collision would ensure the existence of the graviton?

Tags: gravity, particle-physics, quantum-gravity

I understand that particles are smashed together to try to enable us to detect some sort of graviton presence but we can't actually detect a graviton due to the fact that it 'exists' in some extra dimension that we are unable to see, so what are the results we would want to see from colliding 2 particles to be able to be sure of the existence of the graviton?

Comment: No particle collider experiments are likely to produce gravitons or probe quantum gravitational effects any time in the near future.

Comment: ... and I`ve heard that the RS gravitons, which could have been observable at the LHC, are pretty much excluded by now.

Comment: I think it is more accurate to say that particle collider experiments are not likely to produce energetic gravitons that could have observable consequences.  There are undoubtedly gravitons being produced but their energy is so low they make no practical difference in the results.  Just a accelerating charge creates photons, accelerating mass should produce gravitons.

Comment: Olly, if you combine the previous comments, you have your answer... A single ordinary graviton is almost impossible to detect http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0601043 but a graviton from a large fifth dimension might be detectable. Those are the Randall-Sundrum (or Kaluza-Klein) gravitons mentioned by Dilaton.